# Rails3 compatible way of exporting data into yaml and files should be individual records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

https://github.com/adamwiggins/yaml_db is a good tool to dump and then to load data from yaml to tables. However it dumps all the records in one file.

I am looking for a solution which dumps data into individual files for each table name. Is there something that is Rails 3.1 compatible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The currently maintained version of this project seems to do this.

From https://github.com/ludicast/yaml_db README:

```
rake db:data:dump_dir   ->   Dump contents of database to curr_dir_name/tablename.extension (defaults to yaml)
```